# Break not working within my IF statement

Tags: python, break

I'm not sure why my break statement is not working.

```
lst = []

while True:
    try:
        number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
        lst.append(number)
        print lst
        if number == 'q':
            break
    except:
        print "Please enter a number!"
```

Comment: How can `number` be `q` if you convert it to an `int`.

Comment: Ahhh...and thank you for editing for me.  That makes total sense.  I'll go back and rewrite it.  I guess I will turn it into an int within append.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to check **before** you append.

Comment: what do you mean by check exactly?  Excuse my lack of experience, I'm learning python as my first language so i'm very new to this.  Thank you Willem

Comment: the `if` statement should be done **before** you convert it to an `int` (regardless where you do this), since otherwise you will immediately start executing the `except` branch.

Comment: if you mean to put the if statement right below 'try:', I tried that but it just  loops infinitely unfortunately.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you.  I was putting it above everything.  I moved it to below the number = raw_input statement and it works.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you first query for input with `raw_input`, but **immediately** convert it to an `int(..)`.

There are two options: either it succeeds, in which case processing is done by appending it, but in that case `number` can never be `'q'`, or if it is `q`, `int(..)` fails, throws an error, and you will execute the `except:` branch.

You can fix this by first storing the input (for instance in `number`), check if it is `'q'` and if not, process it, something like:

```
lst = []

while True:
    try:
        number = raw_input("Enter a number: ") # no int(..)
        if number == 'q':
            break
        else:
            lst.append(int(number))
            print lst
    except:
        print "Please enter a number!"
```

You can leave the `else:` (only the `else:` not the body of the `else:`) out of the program as @schwobaseggi says.

Comment: No need for the `else` either

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I agree, but it makes the code, in my opinion more *readable* (semantically both are equivalent, but than you have to think about the side effects of the `break`).

Comment: This code should be restructured, which will avoid the need for `else`. First, the call to `raw_input` and the `if` statement can be moved out of the `try` statement. Second, you should not be using a bar `except`; only catch the exception(s) you *know * how to deal with, which in this case is really only the `ValueError` that `int` might raise.